# How to change the directory in python?

Tags: python

My script is under the directory:

`'C:\\Users\\rikesh.kayastha\\project1\\daas\\src'`

My script code is :

```
file_name_csv = "sample.csv"

os.chdir('C:\\Users\\rikesh.kayastha\\project1\\data')
df.to_csv(file_name_csv,index=False,encoding="utf-8")
```

This code saves the csv file in my desired directory. But this is just for local machine. How to adjust this without mentioning the local path. The base path is just `project1` I want to remove the `C:\\Users\\rikesh.kayastha\\` part so that this code will work on every machine.

Comment: " want to remove the C:\\Users\\rikesh.kayastha\\ part" Okay, so, just... *do exactly that*? It's a literal string in your code, you can just edit it so that there is only the remaining part, i.e. `project1\\data`. What actually is the difficulty? Do you understand what *absolute* and *relative* paths are? Do you understand what a *current working directory* is? The only real question I can see here is about how the computer works (specifically, how file paths work), not about how to write Python code.

Comment: "so that this code will work on every machine." *What should happen* when you run the code on another machine? *Where* should the file go? What is the *rule that tells you* where to put the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the user's home directory using `pathlib` with `Path.home()`.

```
from pathlib import Path

file_name_csv = "sample.csv"

user_home_directory = Path.home()
project_directory = user_home_directory / "project1"

output_filepath = project_directory / file_name_csv
df.to_csv(output_filepath, index=False, encoding="utf-8")
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import os 
cudir = os.getcwd()
additional_dir = "\\project1\\data"
newdir = os.path.join(cudir, additional_dir)
print(newdir)
```

Comment: `os.getcwd()` brings the user working directory, which might be different from the script directory

Answer (score 2):

You can use `sys.argv[0]` to get the location of the script on the local machine, which should allow you to locate the data directory aswell

Answer (score 0):

From which directory are you opening your file?

If it is

```
C:\roboczy\PythonScripts\test\project1\daas\src>python main.py
```

Then you can use:

```
filename = "sample.csv"
df.to_csv(f'../../data/{filename}',index=False,encoding="utf-8")
```

If you are ruinning scripts from project1 folder:

```
C:\roboczy\PythonScripts\test\project1>python daas\src\myscript.py
```

Then you can simply use:

```
filename = "sample.csv"
df.to_csv(f'data/{filename}',index=False,encoding="utf-8")
```

Answer (score -1):

Use `pathlib` library.

```
from pathlib import Path 
file_name_csv = "sample.csv"
current_dir = Path(__file__).parent   # returns the folder where your python file is
df.to_csv(current_dir.joinpath(file_name_csv), index=False,encoding="utf-8")
```